# chrome.topSites returning undefined in Microsoft Edge (Chromium)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

I am trying to get the most visited sites in my chrome extension. I have been through Chrome Extension Developer Documentation.

When I trying to get the property `topSites` from the `chrome` object, it returning `undefined`. But as per documentation it available since Chrome 36.

Even I added permission to access `topSites` in `manifest.json`.

```js
//Load top sites
function getTopSites() {
  chrome.topSites.get((top) => {
    console.log(top);
  });
}

getTopSites()
```

When I do print `chrome` object I find nothing property `topSites`. But documentation mention `topSites` available.

```js
//Load top sites
function getTopSites() {
  console.log(chrome);
};

getTopSites()
```

Output in Microsoft Edge

[image: Output chrome object]

```js
"permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "storage",
        "topSites"
    ]
```

I am trying to console the output in the browser's console.

Could anyone tell me what's the problem?

[image: Docs]

Comment: The code is correct and it works in the latest Edge. Make sure you've reloaded the extension on chrome://extensions page after editing manifest.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to make a test with [chrome.topSites](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/topSites) in MS Edge Chromium browser Version 85.0.564.51

I found that it is working fine.

I suggest you try to display it in html file instead of console.

I made a test extension with the below files and code.

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>site list</h2>
    <div id='urls'></div>
    <script src='popup.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
function top_site(urls)
{   
    var url= document.getElementById('urls');
    for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) 
    {
        url.innerHTML += urls[i].url + "<br>";      
    }
}

chrome.topSites.get(top_site);
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "sitelist",
  "version": "101",
  "description": "display site list",
  "permissions": ["topSites"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Output in Edge browser:

[image]

Reference for the extension:

[Top sites sample Extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:topsites)

Comment: Yeah. The problem is when we try to console this.

Comment: @PrathameshMore it means your question doesn't present an [MCVE](/help/mcve). Every detail is important in development of extensions as they have so many moving parts.

Comment: I already described all the important things in question. @wOxxOm

Comment: No, the purpose of [MCVE](/help/mcve) is to help us reproduce the problem. Your question omitted the most important step.

Comment: As per the question. If I trying to console object chrome.topSites. It should be returned. But not in that case. It's returning undefined. @wOxxOm

Comment: There are [multiple different consoles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920982) for each context of an extension. You didn't describe where you are using that code so your question does not contain an [MCVE](/help/mcve). For example, in a content script chrome.topSites is undefined which is the correct behavior. In case it's undefined in an extension page, the cause is different: most likely you didn't reload the extension as I suggested right away. Or maybe you open devtools on edge://extensions page instead of opening devtools for the options page.

Comment: @wOxxOm I updated the question and I added that I was consoling to the browser's console.  Thanks.